# Program going into an infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops, infinite

That's my first question here, so I would be glad to receive some support on the style I used to refer to my problem :). Here is the finished program, its main purpose is to split given words into halves and create words replacing the origin ones. Replaced words are build from its origins by spliting them into halves and taking even ones from the 1st half begining with the first letter of a word. Heres the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void obcinaczSlow(int);

int main(){
    int ilosc;
    cout << "Prosze o podanie ilosci prob: ";
    cin>>ilosc;
    cout << endl;
    obcinaczSlow(ilosc);
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void obcinaczSlow(int ilosc_prob){

    int i=0,j=0,dlugosc_slowa=0,dlugosc_polowy=0;
    string *tablica_slow,budowane_slowo,aktualne_slowo,dodane;
    tablica_slow = new string [ilosc_prob];

    cout << "Prosze o podanie " << ilosc_prob << " slow" << endl;
    cin.sync();
    for(i=0;i<ilosc_prob;i++){
        cout << "Prosze o podanie slowa numer: " << i+1 << endl;
        cin>>aktualne_slowo;
        tablica_slow[i] = aktualne_slowo;
    }

    for(i=0;i<ilosc_prob;i++){
        aktualne_slowo = tablica_slow[i];
        cout << "Aktualne slowo do przerobienia: " << aktualne_slowo << endl;
        dlugosc_slowa = aktualne_slowo.length();
        cout << "Dlugosc slowa do przerobienia: " << dlugosc_slowa << endl;
        dlugosc_polowy = floor(dlugosc_slowa/2);
        cout << "Dlugosc polowy slowa int: " << dlugosc_polowy << endl;
        budowane_slowo.clear();
        dodane.clear();
        cout << "Budowane slowo to: " << budowane_slowo << endl;
        for(j=0;j<=dlugosc_polowy;j=+2){
        dodane = aktualne_slowo.at(j);
        budowane_slowo.append(dodane);
        }
        tablica_slow[i] = budowane_slowo;
    }

    cout << "Slowa po transformacji wygladaja nastepujaco: " << endl;
    for(i=0;i<ilosc_prob;i++){
    cout << "Slowo o numerze " << i+1 << " : " << tablica_slow[i]  << endl;
    }
    delete [] tablica_slow;
    cin.sync();
}
```

The problem raises when program reaches the loop, that is supposed to append the letter pointed by the j-index using '.at' method from the string class. I can't find a solution even trying to debug it. Could You help me :)?

Comment: Just curious, the reason for all three _close_ votes (at the time of this comment) is given as _off-topic_.  Based on the tags of this post, it appears to be precisely _on_ topic.  So, why the down votes?

Comment: @ryyker: The problem has not been whittled down to a small section of code, and it was caused by a typo. This is a Q&A repository and it's hard to see how this question will ever be of use to anyone but the OP.

Comment: try to reduce the code to a minimal case that still reproduces the error. This often helps you understand the problem w/o the need to ask a question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Both (especially _future usefulness_) are good reasons.  Thanks.

Comment: It's best that you debug the program with breakpoints. You can then localise the issue and present that to us so we can help.

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo here

```
for(j=0;j<=dlugosc_polowy;j=+2)
```

I assume you meant `+=` instead of `=+`

```
for(j=0;j<=dlugosc_polowy;j+=2)
```

Otherwise you are just assigning `2` to `j` over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is reversing two characters:
Change:

```
 `j=+2` to `j+=2`
   ^^        ^^
```

(The way it is written `j` is assigned the value of 2, then, for the rest of its life, stays there.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=0;j<=dlugosc_polowy;j=+2){
    dodane = aktualne_slowo.at(j);
    budowane_slowo.append(dodane);
}
```

replace the j=+2 to j+=2

```
for(j=0;j<=dlugosc_polowy;j+=2){
    dodane = aktualne_slowo.at(j);
    budowane_slowo.append(dodane);
}
```